# Spring Integration DSL Custom Error Channel Issue with Executor

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-file

Hi I have a file listener that is reading files parallel / more than one at a time

```
package com.example.demo.flow;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.*;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.channel.MessageChannels;
import org.springframework.integration.file.dsl.Files;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

/**
 * Created by muhdk on 03/01/2020.
 */
@Component
@Slf4j
public class TestFlow {

    @Bean
    public StandardIntegrationFlow errorChannelHandler() {

        return IntegrationFlows.from("testChannel")
                .handle(o -> {

                    log.info("Handling error....{}", o);
                }).get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow testFile() {


        IntegrationFlowBuilder testChannel = IntegrationFlows.from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File("d:/input-files/")),
                e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5000L).maxMessagesPerPoll(5)
                        .errorChannel("testChannel")))
                .channel(MessageChannels.executor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)))
                .transform(o -> {

                    throw new RuntimeException("Failing on purpose");

                }).handle(o -> {
                });

        return testChannel.get();


    }


}
```

Its not going to my custom error channel

but if I remove the line

```
            .channel(MessageChannels.executor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)))
```

Then it goes to error channel.

How can I make it work so that it does go to my custom error channel with executor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like when using Executor services with multiple messages it doesn't work with normal errorChannel which I have no idea why

I made a change like this

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow testFile() {


    IntegrationFlowBuilder testChannel = IntegrationFlows.from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File("d:/input-files/")),
            e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5000L).maxMessagesPerPoll(10)
            ))
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header(MessageHeaders.ERROR_CHANNEL, "testChannel"))
            .channel(MessageChannels.executor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)))

            .transform(o -> {

                throw new RuntimeException("Failing on purpose");

            }).handle(o -> {
            });

    return testChannel.get();


}
```

The line here

```
        .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header(MessageHeaders.ERROR_CHANNEL, "testChannel"))
```

The rest remain the same and it works.

Comment: You finding to fix the issue is correct. Since you shift a work to fully different thread, there is no way to catch an exception in that thread by the `try..catch` in the starting poller. There is just no any errors for that polling thread! So, adding an error channel into headers is the way to go. We can't do that ourselves in the framework because we can't make an assumption that it what you always want to do. Therefore you have to make a decision and apply solution by yourself. See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/error-handling.html#error-handling